# A visual view of source control tree and branches

Tags: version-control, tfs, branch

Is there any utility that works with either Subversion or (preferably) Team Foundation Server's source control system that shows a visual representation of the source tree? e.g. it shows branches (with labels) splitting off, merging back in and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You mean like the Revision Graph, which is built in to Tortoise SVN? You can see a sample of its display capabilities [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-revgraph.html).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the present - go to www.codeplex.com and search for TFS.

In VS2010 there's a very nice feature for that. See [10-4 Episode 4: No More Parallel Development Pain](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/10-4/10-4-Episode-4-No-More-Parallel-Development-Pain). You can download the CTP now, and try it out.

Comment: thanks this is what I am looking for, I guess its not available for TFS2008 though